# Appending from a csv file for each time a function is called

Tags: python, list, function, csv, append

How would I append something to a variable on a list each iteration?
I need to be able to add a number based on the amount of times the function has been called.  For instance if the function was called 3 times, then a certain row from a csv list would be called and that number would be appended to the list.  For example personlist here would look like ['john', '1', '*HERE WOULD BE WHERE THE NUMBER IS ADDED IN*'.

```
personList = []

def number(peopleList):
    personList.append(peopleList[:])
    return personList
```

Massive apologies if this doesn't really make sense !  Finding it fairly hard to articulate what I was trying to achieve here.  But thanks for looking :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, you want to append an incremental counter to each `peopleList` object being added to `personList`.

Going with your code example, a good solution would be for you to declare a global variable and increment it every time your function is called, while also appending it to `peopleList`:

```
personList = []
functionCalls = 0

def number(peopleList):
    global functionCalls
    functionCalls += 1

    # if peopleList is ['john', '1'] then ['john', '1', NUMBER_OF_CALLS] will be appended here.
    personList.append(peopleList[:] + [functionCalls]) 
    return personList
```

Comment: def number(peopleList):
    global functionCalls
    functionCalls += 1
    with open('numbers.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
        reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
        numbersList = list(reader)
  
    personList.append(peopleList[:] + [functionCalls])
    print(personList)
    return personList

Thanks for responding so fast !  I've tried to implement what you said into my code, however the issue is adding the element in the csv list to every element each time.  For instance  ['John', '1', 'Sam', '2'], ['Jack', '1', 'Joe', '2'], 1]]

Comment: The CSV file looks like this 10, 20, 30, 40, 50

Comment: This is very difficult to understand what you want to achieve here...How do you call the function `number`? What does the `peopleList` variable contain?